# Adding values of a second dataFrame depending on the index values of a first dataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a DataFrame that looks like this:

```
   base_rate weighting_factor  
0        NaN                   
1   1.792750                   
2   1.792944
```

I have a second DataFrame that looks like this:

```
   min_index  max_index  weighting_factor
0    0    8              0.15
1    9   17              0.20
2   18   26              0.60
3   27   35              0.80
```

as you can see, the column

> weighting_factor

in the first column is empty. How can I add the weighting_factor from the second dataFrame depending on the index?

For example, I want the weighting factor with the value 0.15 beeing added in the index range 0 - 8 and the weighting factor 0.20 to the index range 9 -17.

Thanks!

EDIT 1:

Instead of

```
>>> df1
    base_rate  weighting_factor
0    0.035007              0.15
1    0.427381              0.15
2    0.791881              0.15
3    0.282179              0.15
4    0.810117              0.15
5    0.871500              0.15
6    0.813326              0.15
7    0.054184              0.15
8    0.795688              0.15
9    0.560442              0.20
10   0.192447              0.20
11   0.712720              0.20
0    0.623351              0.20
1    0.805375              0.20
2    0.484269              0.20
```

I want

A possible solution is to expand your second dataframe:

```
idx = df2.index.repeat(df2['max_index'] - df2['min_index'] + 1)
df1['weighting_factor'] = df2.reindex(idx)['weighting_factor'] .values[:len(df1)]
```

```
>>> df1
    base_rate  weighting_factor
0    0.035007              0.15
1    0.427381              0.15
2    0.791881              0.15
3    0.282179              0.15
4    0.810117              0.20
5    0.871500              0.20
6    0.813326              0.20
7    0.054184              0.20
8    0.795688              0.60
9    0.560442              0.60
10   0.192447              0.60
11   0.712720              0.60
12    0.623351              0.80
13    0.805375              0.80
14    0.484269              0.80
15    0.360207              0.80
16    0.889750              1
17    0.503820              1
18    0.779739              1
19    0.116079              1
20    0.417814              1
21    0.423896              1
22   0.801999              1
23   0.034853              1
```

Since the length of df1 increases, also the range of min_index and max_index increases

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution is to expand your second dataframe:

```
idx = df2.index.repeat(df2['max_index'] - df2['min_index'] + 1)
df1['weighting_factor'] = df2.reindex(idx)['weighting_factor'] .values[:len(df1)]
```

```
>>> df1
    base_rate  weighting_factor
0    0.035007              0.15
1    0.427381              0.15
2    0.791881              0.15
3    0.282179              0.15
4    0.810117              0.15
5    0.871500              0.15
6    0.813326              0.15
7    0.054184              0.15
8    0.795688              0.15
9    0.560442              0.20
10   0.192447              0.20
11   0.712720              0.20
0    0.623351              0.20
1    0.805375              0.20
2    0.484269              0.20
3    0.360207              0.20
4    0.889750              0.20
5    0.503820              0.20
6    0.779739              0.60
7    0.116079              0.60
8    0.417814              0.60
9    0.423896              0.60
10   0.801999              0.60
11   0.034853              0.60
```

Comment: thats a good idea, but it doesn´t work since df1 will be extended multiple times. Thus, the index of the 24 rows long dataframe is now two times 0 - 11

Comment: What do you mean by "df1 will be extended multiple times"? Can you update your post with a sample that does not work with my solution, please?

Comment: df1 is created like that: for i in range (X): add values to df1. Then I do some calculations with df1 for which I need the weighting factor. After some time, additional rows are added to df1 by the loop, then I need to add the the weighting factor again

Comment: What is the problem? Do `weighting factor` changed between the two loops? I leave untouch the index of df1

Comment: When the dataframe hat 12 rows, the index was 0 - 11, which is fine. But after the second run of the loop and thus the increase of the dataframe to 24 rows, the index was 0 - 11 and then again 0 - 11 instead of 0 - 22

Comment: I updated my answer. Can you check it, please? I hope I understood what do you meant.

Comment: Checked, doesn´t work. Sorry, I´m bad at explaining. Your solution now has the problem, that the index 0-11 is repeated, but I want to have the index untouched. Worth to mention: min_index and max_index from the second dataframe are dynamically coded and depend on the amount of rows in the first df.  My goal is basically: df2: take from row 0 the values of min_index and max_index, compare them to the indeces of df1, and if the indexes are equal, fill in the corresponding weighting factor. Then proceed the same way with row1 from df2, take the values in range of min_index and max_index,..

Comment: Use my sample dataframe as input of your question and fill manually the `weighting_factor` as expected outcome, please.

Comment: I did edit the question. If you want, I can add more code if this will help you

Comment: Did you find a solution to your problem because I don't understand how to get your expected output `df1`?